# How to present the labels on the pie in pie chart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw pie graph and want to put labels on the pie.
I have data as below.

```
Group    percent
[0,10]      0
[10,20]     3 
[20,30]    16
[30,40]    11 
[40,50]    23 
[50,60]    5
[60,70]    27
```

Below image is the format that I want.

[image]

**I have written code and some how it doesn't work.
it only returns a percentage of contribution of each value.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
data = df['percent']

labels = ['0~10%', '10~20%', '20~30%', '30~40%', '40~50%', '50~60%','60~70%']
colors = ['#fad9c1','#03396c', '#3b5998', '#63ace5', '#adcbe3','#e3f0ff']


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return labels"\n({:d} hr)".format(pct, absolute)

wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, colors=colors, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
                                  textprops=dict(color="black"))

 
plt.setp(autotexts, size=8, weight="bold")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how you can easily get `autopct` to do what you want.
Referring to the documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html?highlight=pie
it looks like it only takes one parameter, `pct` -- the example lambda function you pulled from calculates the hours for the dynamic label from that parameter. You'd have to figure out how to somehow take that pct and turn it into a lookup from your labels table, doesn't seem straightforward, and you'd have to pass the labels table into the lambda function.

The revision I posted here is a bit of compromise, using the normal label functionality of the `pie` method. It resembles what you stated you were looking for, but your intent is unclear, as the sample data you started with doesn't match the values in your example chart. I've assumed those values are hours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

srcdata = [
    [[0,10],     3],
    [[10,20],     14], 
    [[20, 30],    13],
    [[30, 40],    22],
    [[40, 50],    5],
    [[50, 60],    29],]

df =  pd.DataFrame(srcdata, columns = ['Group', 'hours'])
data = df['hours']

labels = ['0~10%', '10~20%', '20~30%', '30~40%', '40~50%', '50~60%'] #,'60~70%']
colors = ['#03396c', '#3b5998', '#63ace5', '#adcbe3', '#e3f0ff', '#fad9c1' ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

# This prints the percentage and *calculates* the hours.
def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:.1f}%\n{:d} hr\n".format(pct, absolute)

# Simply don't print the percentage.
def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:d} hr\n".format(absolute)

wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, colors=colors, labels = labels, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
                                  textprops=dict(color="black"))
 
plt.setp(autotexts, size=8, weight="bold")

plt.show()
```